# freemarker error: expected hash. evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleScalar

Tags: freemarker

My template looks like this:

```
  <#assign senti = "${scmr.results[model]}">
    <#if senti??>
      <td>${senti} ---- ${senti.sentimentType}</td>
      <td>${senti.score?html}</td>
    </#if>
```

The output looks like this:

```
POSITIVE(1.0/1) ---- Expected hash. senti evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleScalar on line 5, column 27 in com/addthis/sentiment/sentidemo.ftl.
```

the output text before "----" indicates that **senti** is, indeed, a valid java **Sentiment** object. Methods **getSentimentType** and **getScore** are present and working.

So, why am I getting the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `<#assign senti = "${scmr.results[model]}">` you have converted `scmr.results[model]` to a String (a scalar), that's why. Just write `<#assign senti = scmr.results[model]>`. In FreeMarker expressions you can inject value into a **string literal**, like `"Hello ${name}!"` (same as `"Hello " + name + "!"`), and `"${someExpression}"` is just a case of that. It's not like in JSP.

Answer (score 0):

had the same error when using swagger generated models with ninjaframework , fixed by adding below class in conf package

```
package conf;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper;
import freemarker.ext.beans.MethodAppearanceFineTuner;
import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder;
import ninja.NinjaDefault;
import ninja.template.TemplateEngineFreemarker;

/**
 * Created by varya on 07/12/17.
 */
public class Ninja extends NinjaDefault {
    @Inject
    protected TemplateEngineFreemarker templateEngineFreemarker;

    @Override
    public void onFrameworkStart() {
        super.onFrameworkStart();

        Configuration freemarkerConfiguration = templateEngineFreemarker.getConfiguration();
        DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder owb = new DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23);
        owb.setMethodAppearanceFineTuner(new MethodAppearanceFineTuner() {
            @Override
            public void process(BeansWrapper.MethodAppearanceDecisionInput in, BeansWrapper.MethodAppearanceDecision out) {
                out.setMethodShadowsProperty(false);
            }
        });

        freemarkerConfiguration.setObjectWrapper(owb.build());


    }



}
```